# How to split one column with array merge value to array and join other table then merge back

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There's a table WaitCheckBil like :

```
| BIL\_NO | USRS | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XC20090015 | ;STO09;STO02;STO04;STO06;STO10;STO07;STO10; | 2020\-09\-15 00:00:00.000 |
| XC20090016 | ;STO09;STO02;STO04;STO06;STO10;STO07;STO10; | 2020\-09\-15 00:00:00.000 |
| XC20090017 | ;STO09;STO02;STO04;STO06;STO10;STO07;STO10; | 2020\-09\-15 00:00:00.000 |
| XC20090018 | ;STO09;STO02;STO04;STO06;STO10;STO07;STO10; | 2020\-09\-16 00:00:00.000 |
```

and a table Users like :

```
| USR | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| STO02 | John |
| STO04 | Eva |
| STO06 | Lisa |
| STO07 | Boke |
| STO09 | Nii |
| STO10 | Alisa |
```

Expected result :

```
| BIL\_NO | USRS | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XC20090015 | ;Nii;John;Eva;Lisa;Alisa;Boke;Alisa; | 2020\-09\-15 00:00:00.000 |
| XC20090016 | ;Nii;John;Eva;Lisa;Alisa;Boke;Alisa; | 2020\-09\-15 00:00:00.000 |
| XC20090017 | ;Nii;John;Eva;Lisa;Alisa;Boke;Alisa; | 2020\-09\-15 00:00:00.000 |
| XC20090018 | ;Nii;John;Eva;Lisa;Alisa;Boke;Alisa; | 2020\-09\-16 00:00:00.000 |
```

What I've tried & think :

It's a old system's table , so I can't change the struct.
And the table logic is `select * from WaitCheckBil where usrs like '%;' + @usr + ';%';` to get user's wait check bil_NO.

I think it could split `;` usrs column value to array , then join with users table on user column, then merge back to users column.

But I have trouble on here , I have no idea how to implement the logic on `sql-server 2008`.

Online demo link : [SQL Server 2017 | db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c17c30c4212d4cd6489333ad00511638)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so here's a UDF for SQL Server 2008:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufnReplaceUIDs(@inUIDs varchar(100))
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS   
--  Replace User Ids with User Names
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @UID varchar(10);
    DECLARE @outUNames varchar(100);  
    DECLARE @outUName varchar(10);
    DECLARE @String varchar(100);
    SET @String = SUBSTRING(@inUIDs, 2, LEN(@inUIDs) - 1)  -- Remove First/Last ; 
    WHILE (CHARINDEX(';', @String) > 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @UID = LEFT(@String, CHARINDEX(';', @String) - 1);
            SELECT @OutUName = [NAME] FROM Users WHERE [USR] = @UID; 
            SET @OutUNames = CONCAT(@OutUNames, ';', @OutUName); 
            SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String, CHARINDEX(';', @String) + 1, 100);
        END;
    RETURN CONCAT(@outUNames, ';');  
END;
```

Use it like so: `SELECT [BIL_NO], dbo.ufnReplaceUIDs([USRS]) AS [USRS], [DATE] FROM WaitCheckBil` and the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use STRING_SPLIT and STRING_AGG functions together, something like this (I've added it to your fiddle):

```
WITH uSplit AS (
SELECT [BIL_NO], [DATE], [USR], [NAME] FROM WaitCheckBil as wcb 
OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(SUBSTRING(wcb.[USRS], 2, LEN(wcb.usrs) - 2), ';') AS S
LEFT JOIN Users AS U on U.[USR] = S.[value]
)
SELECT [BIL_NO], CONCAT(';', STRING_AGG([NAME], ';'), ';') AS [USRS], [DATE]
  FROM uSplit
 GROUP BY [BIL_NO], [DATE]
```

Oops, sorry. I saw your fiddle was SQL Server 2017 and assumed that was OK. Are you needing SQL Server 2008? I see that STRING_SPLIT and STRING_AGG didn't arrive until 2016/2017 versions. You may need to write a UDF to get the same result in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Thanks, Yes , my trouble is at `sql-server 2008` ... but you can keep the answer if no new answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Could you make use of a UDF to do this?